# Apply filter for GHE issues

Tags: java, github, github-api

I want to get all issues from GHE using Java API client without issues with label "insfrastructure"

I tried this:

```
                map.put(IssueService.FILTER_STATE, IssueService.STATE_CLOSED);
                map.put(IssueService.FIELD_DIRECTION, sort_direction);
                map.put(IssueService.FIELD_SINCE, date_from);
                map.put(IssueService.FIELD_FILTER, "-label:infrastructure");
```

But still I get issues with this label. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to add double quotes ? `map.put(IssueService.FIELD_FILTER, "-label:\"infrastructure\"");`

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of IssueService.FIELD_FILTER usage in [`src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/issue/IssueDashboardPagerAdapter.java`](https://github.com/ksoichiro/android/blob/fbfb63c6607d8077018c245d7508f0fedab65dbb/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/issue/IssueDashboardPagerAdapter.java#L63-L83)

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    String filter = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        filter = FILTER_SUBSCRIBED;
        break;
    case 1:
        filter = FILTER_ASSIGNED;
        break;
    case 2:
        filter = FILTER_CREATED;
        break;
    case 3:
        filter = FILTER_MENTIONED;
        break;
    default:
        return null;
    }
    final Map<String, String> filterData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    filterData.put(FIELD_FILTER, filter);
```

Those filter values reference pre-defined values in [`org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/IssueService.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/aaf575a899df8aac9f3a74fab77a6b10007b6b39/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/IssueService.java#L54-L99)

That include labels.

```
/**
 * Filter by issue's labels
 */
public static final String FILTER_LABELS = "labels"; //$NON-NLS-1$
```

label*s*, with an 's'.

Used as:

```
    List<Label> labels = issue.getLabels();
    if (labels != null) {
        List<String> labelNames = new ArrayList<String>(labels.size());
        for (Label label : labels)
            labelNames.add(label.getName());
        params.put(FILTER_LABELS, labelNames);
    }
```

Comment: I tested your proposal but it's not working - the list is empty.

Comment: @PeterPenzov OK: try and launch your program in debug mode, to see what variables are actually valued.